# I wish I could create custom view with tableview in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, xcode5, uiview-hierarchy

I'm having trouble creating a view hierarchy. I'm developing a custom `UIView` to display a list.

Here is what I would like to achieve:

[image: Please take a look]

Instead, I'm getting the following weird output:

[image: Here]

I want the OK button to be at a specific X,Y position.

**My Current View Hierarchy is like **

- UIView
- ContainerView-(CustomView to show tableview with UIButton)
- ContainerView contains UITableView,UILabel,UIButton (with titled OK )

Sorry for my English :)

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to achieve and what your implementation is currently doing.

Comment: you can add your button as footer of UITableView.

Comment: What constraints have you added to the various components?